# One week after a specific date in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

Do you have any ideas on how I can specify the date of the week after a specific date? I'm using a datepicker to have my start time and this how I convert it into date.

```
$formatdate = str_replace("(/\)", "-", $startdate);
$time2 = strtotime( $formatdate );
$date = date('Y-m-d', $time);
```

I will need to know the date after 1 week of the start date in order to use it at my mysql query just like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$stardate' AND '$enddate'
```

Thank you guys! Any help will be fully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$formatdate = str_replace("(/\)", "-", $startdate);
$start = new DateTime( $formatdate );
$startdate = $start->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$next_week = clone $start;
$next_week->add(new DateInterval("P1W"));
$enddate = $next_week->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$stardate' AND '$enddate'";
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm did some editing to your code and finally made it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$currentDate=date("Y-m-d");
$dateOneWeekAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)) . " +1 week");
echo date("Y-m-d",$dateOneWeekAdded);
?>
```

**Edit :** For specific date, you can rewrite above code as

```
<?php
$currentDate="08/14/2012";
$dateOneWeekAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)) . " +1 week");
echo date("Y-m-d",$dateOneWeekAdded);
?>
```

Comment: not working for me. prints series of numbers. not a date. my input date is 08/14/2012 the result is 1345305600

Comment: @ljpv14, it works, you have to format using date function just see last line of my above code `echo date("Y-m-d",$dateOneWeekAdded); It gives result 2012-08-21, as today is 2012-08-14
`

Comment: @ljpv14, please see my updated code above, copy and paste whole code block to test

Answer (score 0):

Less lines of code:

```
$end = new DateTime("today +1 week"); 
print $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

And for a given date:

```
$start = "2012-10-24";
$end = new DateTime("$start +1 week"); 
print $end->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it with MySQL:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '$stardate' AND DATE_ADD('$stardate', INTERVAL 7 DAY)`